# QR Scanner URL string to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, popup, wkwebview, popover

İs there any possibility to scan QR code by QR-scanner and get URL string in a popup or popover window which contains only WKWebView in swift. İ have tried to figure out but not found in this regard. Need to open url in webview but popup. Or any related good suggestions !!!.
**Note: My QR part is completed.**

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Comment: Hi @Newbie. Can you share more for better explanation please?

Comment: @EmreCiftci İ need to open URL like www.google.com (scanned from QR image) to WKWebview control but in popup window. As my QR scans the image, decode it to url popup windows come up and url website open (webview) or any other easy solution.

Comment: Did you get the url from the QR? @Newbie

Comment: @EmreCiftci yes, QR part is completed even I am displaying it. Only need some interactive thing.